# How will passport-local work with simple json-file not database?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Need some explanation about `passport.serializeUser()` and `passport.deserializeUser()` when not using any database for `local-strategy` and storing the information in simple `json file`.

How passport determine the id and how it retrieve back in `deserializeUser()`?

```
passport.use(
        'local-signup',
        new LocalStrategy(
        {
                usernameField: 'email',
                passwordField: 'password',
                passReqToCallback: true
            },
            function(request, email, password, done) {
                process.nextTick(
                    function() {
                        if(user.doesUserExist(email)) {
                            return done(
                                null,
                                false, 
                                request.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.')
                            );
                        }
                        else {
                          var newUser = user.createNewUser(email, password);
                            return done(null, {email: newUser.username, password: newUser.password});
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        )
    );



// Used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(
    function serializeUserCB(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    }
);

// Used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(
    function deserializeUserCB(id, done) {
        done(null, id);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Passport maintains aunthentication state in sessions, thus you need to define 2 functions `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deSerializeUser` for serializing/deserializing user instances to and from the session.

Each subsequent request will not contain credentials, but rather the unique cookie that identifies the session in order to support login sessions.

For serializing and deserializing it uses secret key from

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'ThIsIsAsEcREtKEy',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Just use serializeUser and deserializeUser as

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    done(null, id);
});
```

for local Json file.